# Encender el led Flash presionando un item en Action bar

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de encender el flash del celular a modo de linterna, desde un item en el action bar, pero no logro encenderlo, el código es e el siguiente:

Variable delcara al inicio de la calse para manejar el encendido y apagado:

```
    boolean isOn = false;
```

Opciones del menú:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.btnOtro) {

    }
    if(id== R.id.btnFlash) {

        if(isOn==false)
            isOn=true;
        else{
            isOn=false;
        }
        flash();
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Y este es el método para enceder el flash:

```
     public void flash()//  metodo para activar el flash
    {
    if(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {

        camera= Camera.open();
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
    }

    if(isOn==true)
    {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    else
    {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
}
```

si alguien soluciono algo así sería muy útil que me compartiera, Gracias.

Comment: Me parece que para usar el flash debes dar permisos de Camera, agrega al manifest.xml los permisos requeridos, mírate ese enlace que da soporte para Android 6.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Tienes agregados los permisos en el `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

En cuanto a tu validación que determina si tu dispositivo tiene flash debes cambiarla, ya que seguramente esta regresando un valor falso por esa razón no abre la cámara.

```
if(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
...
```

a  :

```
if(hasFlash()) {
...
```

usando este método:

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
        if (camera == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
            return false;
        }    
        List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }
```